# Omnet++ simple wireless node

Tags: omnet++

Iam trying to create simple wireless node for MANET network which can send messages to other nodes in range. Solutions implemented in INET also contains other layers like IP, transport, application which i dont need.

Iam new to omnet++ so iam struggling a bit. I was thinking of creating whole own node with RadioIn input, but i dont know how to implement only in range communication and i will also need node mobility.

Other solutions would be to use only Radiomedium from INET framework but i dont know how to do it.

Can someone please give me some begginer tips how to achieve my goal? As i said i simply need to create mobile host which can send a defined message to all other hosts in range.

**EDIT:** I tried to take IdealRadioMedium and create my simple module and connect to it. Here is the NED File.

```
import inet.physicallayer.common.packetlevel.Radio;
import inet.common.figures.DelegateSignalConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.INetworkNode;
import inet.node.inet.WirelessHost;
import inet.physicallayer.contract.packetlevel.IRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.integrated.IntegratedCanvasVisualizer;
import inet.linklayer.contract.IWirelessNic;
import inet.networklayer.common.InterfaceTable;

simple Txc1
{
    gates:
        input in;
        output out;
}

module Pokusny
{
    parameters:
       @display("i=device/wifilaptop");
       int numRadios = default(1);
       @networkNode;

    gates:
         input radioIn[numRadios] @directIn;

    submodules:
        mynode: Txc1;
        wlan[numRadios]: <default("Ieee80211Nic")> like IWirelessNic {
            parameters:
                @display("p=216,406,row,60;q=queue");
        }
        interfaceTable: InterfaceTable {
            parameters:
                @display("p=53,300;is=s");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:     
        for i=0..sizeof(radioIn)-1 {
            radioIn[i] --> { @display("m=s"); } --> wlan[i].radioIn;
            wlan[i].upperLayerOut -->  mynode.in;
            wlan[i].upperLayerIn <--  mynode.out;
        }
}

network WirelessC
{
    parameters:
        string hostType = default("WirelessHost");
        string mediumType = default("IdealRadioMedium");

        @display("bgb=650,500;bgg=100,1,grey95");
        @figure[title](type=label; pos=0,-1; anchor=sw; color=darkblue);

        @figure[rcvdPkText](type=indicatorText; pos=420,20; anchor=w; font=,20; textFormat="packets received: %g"; initialValue=0);
        @statistic[rcvdPk](source=hostB_rcvdPk; record=figure(count); targetFigure=rcvdPkText);
        @signal[hostB_rcvdPk];
        @delegatesignal[rcvdPk](source=hostB.udpApp[0].rcvdPk; target=hostB_rcvdPk);

    submodules:
        visualizer: IntegratedCanvasVisualizer {
            @display("p=580,125");
        }

        configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=580,200");
        }
        radioMedium: <mediumType> like IRadioMedium {
            @display("p=580,275");
        }
        //figureHelper: DelegateSignalConfigurator {
        //    @display("p=580,350");
        //}
        hostA: Pokusny {
            @display("p=50,325");
        }
        hostB: Pokusny {
            @display("p=450,325");
        }
}
```

Txc1.cc

```
class Txc1 : public cSimpleModule
{
  protected:
    // The following redefined virtual function holds the algorithm.
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};
// The module class needs to be registered with OMNeT++
Define_Module(Txc1);

void Txc1::initialize()
{
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("tictocMsg");
        send(msg, "out");
}
void Txc1::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    send(msg, "out"); // send out the message
}
```

And .ini file

```
network = WirelessC
sim-time-limit = 25s


*.host*.wlan[0].typename = "IdealWirelessNic"
*.host*.wlan[0].mac.useAck = false
*.host*.wlan[0].mac.fullDuplex = false
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.transmitter.communicationRange = 500m
*.host*.wlan[0].radio.receiver.ignoreInterference = true

*.host*.**.bitrate = 1Mbps
```

When i run the simulation it asks for Interfacetable parameter which i dont know what to type there becuse i havent found it in traversing functioning code ( I had to add it because it throws error that is missing if its not as submodule). Now iam getting

getCointainingNode() node module not found it should have a property name networkNode for module WirelessC.interfaceTable in module .... durint network initialization

**EDIT:** I added networknode as parameter and now i got Module not found on path '.mobility' defined by par WirelessC.hostA.wlan[0].radio.antenna.Mobilitymodule in module inte::physicallayer:IsotropicAntenna during network initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to point you to the wireless tutorial for INET: https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/tutorials/wireless/

It starts with exactly your problem. The only thing left, is to replace the standard UDP host with a host using no protocol at all, maybe even implementing your own. The whole wireless part is explained in the tutorial.

If you want to check the source files for the used modules you need to walk down the chain of dependency since every compound NED module will (at one point)  contain simple modules implemented in C++.
E.g. the module which is responsible for distributing the signals is `IdealRadioMedium` using [RadioMedium](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/integration/src/inet/physicallayer/common/packetlevel/RadioMedium.h). Now you need to find the Node implementation directly communicating with this module.
Starting with the `WirelessHost` used in the tutorial the underlying modules are
`StandardHost` -> `ApplicationLayerNodeBase` -> [LinkLayerNodeBase](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/integration/src/inet/node/base/LinkLayerNodeBase.ned) with the later being the first one using actually implemented submodules.
The network adapter used is configured in the `omnet.ini` with `*.host*.wlan[0].typename = "IdealWirelessNic"`. This module relies on [Radio](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/integration/src/inet/physicallayer/common/packetlevel/Radio.cc).

With all that found out you just need to look for API calls from Radio.cc made to RadioMedium.cc and you found the actual code responsible for sending data.
Understanding that chain of inheritance you can even hook in with your custom module at a level you find fitting. For example just implementing your own LinklayerNodeBase module.

Comment: I already covered mentioned tutorial, but all examples are only using .ned and .ini files so no actual .cc files with behavior are shown. I want to use only IdealRadio (if it is enagouh for sending custom message to all nodes in range) but i dont know how to do it in my custom created project and how to override it and which function is used for sending messages and so.

Comment: Thanks, thats more closer to what i need but iam still a bit lost :( because its complicated to a starter like me. See edit of original answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for wireless communication and mobility, INET will still be the best framework to use.

Check out [the INET Wireless Tutorial](https://inet.omnetpp.org/inet-tutorials//wireless/doc/). It basically covers all the steps that you need to build a small scenario with moving nodes that communicate wirelessly.